# How tax is applied on the bundle products?

Tags: magento

I am using bundle products with  *`fixed SKU`* , *`fixed price`* and *`dynamic weight`*.

I want to know how the tax is applied on bundle products?

Suppose I am applying tax 8% to the goods which are shipped to Newyork.
This will be applied as the whole or for all the individual bundle selection?

what point should I remember while calculating tax on bundle products.

Please guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pricing will determine the tax calculation.

Since you are using a fixed price, the tax will not be calculated for the individual items. Set the tax class on the bundle product itself.